# How can i Split the large image into small tiles based on zoom

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I want to split large images into small tiles based on zoom level automatically.

That means when I upload the image it will automatically split into tiles and store in some output folder.

Then I can use those tiles as map by using `leaflet.js`.

Comment: Please at least attempt to solve the problem, then approach us with any issues you have. Stack overflow isn't a private code writing service

Comment: Hi @Takarii thank you for advice , i need only some suggestions to get my requirement

Comment: Keep in mind, that looking for software suggestions is off topic for SO. See [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be interested in software that do this process for you, like MapTiler, zoomify…

Of course you can also do it yourself, you just need to use image handling libraries to cut your image into tiles, zoom it down and repeat the process.

Or usually the reverse: zoom down your image until it fits a single tile, then zoom it down until it is twice as big as the previous step, cut into 4 tiles, etc.

Comment: Thank you ghybs for your answer, as you mentioned i am interesting  in software

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! :-) Next time, please make sure to be explicit in your need, in order to avoid misunderstanding from some people. Additionally, you might also be interested in [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) for similar questions.